# How Get All Camera Devices ID From PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, webcam

I am trying to get all camera devices ID and respective names using PowerShell command line. I tried several commands, but nothing has done what I am aiming. Below my "best" approach:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | where caption -match 'camera'
```

**output**

```
Caption                     : Remote Desktop Camera Bus
Description                 : UMBus Enumerator
InstallDate                 :
Name                        : Remote Desktop Camera Bus
Status                      : OK
Availability                :
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity
DeviceID                    : UMB\UMB\1&841921D&0&RDCAMERA_BUS
ErrorCleared                :
ErrorDescription            :
LastErrorCode               :
PNPDeviceID                 : UMB\UMB\1&841921D&0&RDCAMERA_BUS
PowerManagementCapabilities :
PowerManagementSupported    :
StatusInfo                  :
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : DESKTOP
ClassGuid                   : {4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
CompatibleID                :
HardwareID                  : {UMB\UMBUS}
Manufacturer                : Microsoft
PNPClass                    : System
Present                     : True
Service                     : umbus
PSComputerName              :
```

I know, for example, that generally the integrated camera has a name "integrated camera" with a ID "0". But this is not what is being shown.

Comment: How do you "know" that's what they're labeled?

Comment: I already did this in C using `MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID` and  `include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfobjects.h>
#include <Mfidl.h>`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Now that you know that, do you know how to answer my question?

Comment: So, you're saying that attribute gives you those properties? You can use P/Invoke

Comment: Could you show me exactly how to use it on Power shell?

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | ? { $_.service -eq "usbvideo" } | Select-Object -Property PNPDeviceID, Name
```